# PyCharm: Automatically scroll to end (Running tests)

Tags: pycharm

I want a fast edit-test loop.

The interesting output is at the end of the stacktrace I see if a test fails.

If I hit ctrl-shift-F10 the current test gets executed.

I see the output in the windows, but by default I see the top of the output.

I know the "Scroll to end" button, but I don't want this loop:

1. edit code
2. execute test
3. click on button "scroll to end"
4. see the last lines of the output

I want this loop:

1. edit code
2. execute test
3. see the last lines of the output

Is there a way to automatically scroll to the end of the output of my test?